# What's more efficient, array formulas or individual formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Simple question: 
When adding, multiplying, or otherwise doing simple operations on two ranges is it better to use array formulas or individual formulas?

=A1+B1

=A2+B2

=A3+B3

vs

{A1:A3 + B1:B3}

Array Formula Advantages:

- Can't edit part of an array (less error prone)
- Maybe easier to understand?

Single Formula dragged down the range

- This is what people typically do

Can't find any guidance so maybe it really doesn't matter from a performance standpoint? Is it only personal preference?

Comment: it doesn't matter.  Excel is going to handle the formula exactly the same way.

Comment: @Ramhound - that's not true, advanced Excel users know that array formulas work *different* and some calculations can be accomplished only through them. Let me post an answer.

Comment: @miroxlav the ability to do different *types* of calculations doesn't affect how excel handles the operation. You can come up with incredible formulas, but they are still handled as formulas. This question is incredibly broad.

Comment: Makes sense, I meant the question to be broad. Basically was just curious about broad "best practices" for formula design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most significant difference is that with array formulas you can calculate things which are not possible to achieve using standard formulas.

For example, using `SUM()` with array formula, you can sum products!

```
{=SUM(B2:F2*B3:F3)}
```

This is out of reach of standard formulas.

For more, please watch [short intro to array formulas](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-GB/article/array-formulas-8ff8257a-b28e-4e81-b4f8-30f793412dfa).

Now, if you are asking which are more efficient: each type has its own application, we can stop comparing there. But if you want to use them for the same task, array formulas can be a bit faster, but a bit more difficult for editing. For example, you can expand range of array formula by mouse, but you cannot shrink it etc. As a side effect, you can't easily overwrite array formula ranges. Is it better? For someone, perhaps. But this was attempt on "comparison" of two things which are actually a bit different in their nature.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I am at a point where I'm building a lot of sheets and wanted to figure out a best practice. I will experiment with both. I've enjoyed '{=STDEV.S(IF($A5=prospects,lbRod1k))}' uses of array formulas with the if statement. Thank you again!

Comment: @KevinPresley - Hi Kevin, you are welcome! Here at [su] site, actions are expected to finalize every given question. Please mark helpful answer with check mark and optionally also upvote it. This will give other readers indication of what answered your problem.